# React Native/Typescript/Eslint error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'CompositeAnimation'

Tags: typescript, react-native, animation

I am new to typescript. The linter has been able to Quick fix for me but the following section of code offers no quick actions available for the linter to fix with:

The problem message is "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'CompositeAnimation'.ts(2322)"

```
Animated.parallel([
     Animated.spring(this.position, {
         toValue: ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
     }).start(),
     Animated.spring(this.swipeCardPosition, {
         toValue: ({ x: 0, y: -SCREEN_HEIGHT }),
     }).start(),
]).start();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that the Animated.parallel() method accepts an array of composite animation objects. Animate.spring() returns a composite animation object, but you call the start() method on both of these animations, which has a return type of void.

Try the following code, I think it should work accordingly:

```
Animated.parallel([
 Animated.spring(this.position, {
     toValue: ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
 }),
 Animated.spring(this.swipeCardPosition, {
     toValue: ({ x: 0, y: -SCREEN_HEIGHT }),
 }),
]).start();
```

Notice that I didn't start the spring animations, I just start the "root" animation which contains the two spring animations.

I hope it will help you.